# Jupyter notebook open link in new tab

Tags: jupyter

I want to make hyperlinks in my Jupyter Notebook to open in a new tab. But, I don't know how to do it. Suggestions?

```
I want this [link](url) to open in a new tab.
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to this question.  What have you tried?  Can you show some small source examples?  What docs have you read?

Answer (score 6):

If for some reason you need to force links to open in a new tab, Jupyter's markdown cells will render pure html, where you can use the `target` attribute.

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">link</a>
```

That said with Jupyter 4.2.0 I get the behavior that you request by default: markdown links automatically open in a new tab.

Comment: This worked well and didn't require doing anything extra, just do this instead of `[link](url)`

Answer (score 2):

This works well ! Try it !

```
[example.com](http://example.com/)
```

Comment: That's a normal link that opens in the same tab

Answer (score 0):

This solution is worked for me:

> Surround the link with two underscores (_) on each side [IBM Docs - Markdown for Jupyter notebooks cheatsheet](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watson-studio-local/1.2.3?topic=notebooks-markdown-jupyter-cheatsheet)

`__[link text](http://url)__`

Comment: This just made it bold for me